# Simplifying use of lambda expressions and memoizing a Map in the State Monad

Tags: haskell, memoization

This function is much faster than its recursive version:

```
crossSubstrings :: String -> String -> [(String,String)]
crossSubstrings string1 string2 = [(substr1,substr2) | substr1 <- inits string1,
                                                       substr2 <- inits string2]

type Distances = Map.Map (String,String) Int

editDistanceMemoized :: String -> String -> Int
editDistanceMemoized s1 s2 = 
   let 
     substrings = s1 `crossSubstrings` s2
     distances = foldl (editDistance) emptyMap substrings
   in
     distances Map.! (s1,s2)
   where 
     emptyMap = Map.fromList []
     editDistance :: Distances -> (String,String) -> Distances
     editDistance map ([],s1) = map `Map.union` getMap [] s1 (length s1)
     editDistance map (s1,[]) = map `Map.union` getMap s1 [] (length s1)
     editDistance map (s1,s2) = map `Map.union` getMap s1 s2 (cost map s1 s2)
     getMap s1 s2 d = Map.fromList [((s1,s2),d)]
     insertionPCost = \m -> \s1 -> \s2 -> m Map.! (s1, init s2) + 1
     deletionPCost = \m -> \s1 -> \s2 -> m Map.! (init s1, s2)  + 1
     substitutionPCost = \m -> \s1 -> \s2 -> m Map.! (init s1, init s2)
                                             + substitutionCostIfNEQ s1 s2
     substitutionCostIfNEQ = \s1 -> \s2 -> if (last s1 == last s2) then 0 else 2
     cost = \m -> \s1 -> \s2 -> minimum [insertionPCost m s1 s2,
                                         deletionPCost m s1 s2,
                                         substitutionPCost m s1 s2]
```

However (first question), I feel like some lambdas could be avoided (doesn't it look repetitive? look specially at `cost`). Is there a way to compose `minimum` ?

In addition, the State Monad could be used to propagate the map (instead of using `foldl`?). Despite despite reading how `State.>>=` and `State.id` behave, I'm not 100% sure how the signature should look like (second question).

I thought of this one, where the state is "the next pair of strings to be measured" and Distances contains the memoized distances.

```
 editDistance :: State Distances (String,String) -> State Distances ()?
```

Comment: Incidentally, your `emptyMap` is the same as [`Map.empty`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html#v:empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertionPCost`, `deletionPCost`, `substitutionPCost` and `substitutionCostIfNEQ` are only called from each other and `cost`, and always with the same arguments (save that `substitutionCostIfNEQ` doesn't take `m`); so we can rearrange them like this:

```
cost = \m -> \s1 -> \s2 -> minimum [insertionPCost, deletionPCost, substitutionPCost] 
  where insertionPCost = m Map.! (s1, init s2) + 1
        deletionPCost = m Map.! (init s1, s2)  + 1
        substitutionPCost = m Map.! (init s1, init s2) + substitutionCostIfNEQ
        substitutionCostIfNEQ = if (last s1 == last s2) then 0 else 2
```

And the explicit lambdas aren't getting you anything, so rewrite to be clearer:

```
cost m s1 s2 = minimum [insertionPCost, deletionPCost, substitutionPCost] 
  where insertionPCost = m Map.! (s1, init s2) + 1
        deletionPCost = m Map.! (init s1, s2)  + 1
        substitutionPCost = m Map.! (init s1, init s2) + substitutionCostIfNEQ
        substitutionCostIfNEQ = if (last s1 == last s2) then 0 else 2
```

---

To answer your second question, currently you have

```
editDistance :: Distances -> (String,String) -> Distances
```

If you were to use `State` instead, that would be

```
editDistance :: (String,String) -> State Distances ()
```

That is, `editDistance` would be a function that takes `(String,String)`, and yields something that interacts with a `Distances` state, and no other meaningful result.

But.

Firstly, I don't see that there's anything wrong with your use of `foldl`.

Secondly, you never really use the accumulated value, what would be the state. You use it to make a new value, but you don't look anything up in it. So you don't need `State`, you only need `Writer`.

```
editDistance :: (String,String) -> Writer Distances ()
```

That is, `editDistance` would be a function that takes `(String,String)`, and yields something that adds to a `Distances` accumulator, and no other meaningful result.

(There's a subtlety here: the first parameter to `Writer` has to be a `Monoid`, and it has to use the combining operation (`mappend`) that's useful to you; well, `Map`s are `Monoid`s, and their `mappend` is the same `union` that you use in your original `editDistance`, so it all works out fine.)

Comment: Oh thanks, I remember trying two nested where's and failing, now it works and it looks cleaner.

Comment: Thank you! there was nothing wrong with foldl, I just wanted to learn the monadic solution.